# How to calculate heightForRowAtIndexPath for cells which setup via switch in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I setup my cells like this:

So, a couple of switches, define the cells, because the data is not in the list of objects, but a set of information which should be displayed in a tableView in some different ways.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)value1CellForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    static NSString *CellIdentifierValue1 = @"Value1Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifierValue1];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifierValue1];
        cell.detailTextLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        cell.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    }
    return cell;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:
            //Coupon
            switch (indexPath.row) {
                case 0:
                    //Couponcode
                    cell = [self value1CellForTableView:tableView];
                    cell.textLabel.text = @"Code";
                    cell.detailTextLabel.text = presentedCoupon.couponNr;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    //Coupondescription
                    cell = [self value1CellForTableView:tableView];
                    cell.detailTextLabel.text = presentedCoupon.couponDescription;
                    cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
                    cell.textLabel.text =@"Ihr Vorteil";
                    break;

            }        
            break;


        case 1:
            //Productinfo
            switch (indexPath.row) {
                case 0:
                    cell = [self defaultCellForTableView:tableView];
                    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]  stringByAppendingPathComponent: [presentedCoupon.refProdName stringByAppendingString:@".png"]]];
                    cell.textLabel.text = presentedCoupon.refProdName;
                    break;



            }
            break;  

        case 2:
            //Shopinfo
            switch (indexPath.row) {
                case 0:
                    cell = [self defaultCellForTableView:tableView];
                    cell.textLabel.text = ((Shop*)presentedCoupon.refShop).name;
                    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;

                    break;    
            }
            break;       
    }

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [self defaultCellForTableView:tableView];
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Stanni";
    }
    [cell layoutIfNeeded];
    return cell;
}
```

And i calculate the height like this.

```
 -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        NSLog(@"height");
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    CGFloat height = 24 + [cell.detailTextLabel.text sizeWithFont:cell.detailTextLabel.font constrainedToSize: CGSizeMake(cell.detailTextLabel.frame.size.width, 1000.0f) lineBreakMode:cell.detailTextLabel.lineBreakMode].height;

    return MAX(height, 44.0f);
```

**Problem:**

The problem is, as mentioned in many threads, and also visible in my log, that the height of each cell, (visible or not) is asked at the initialization of the table view. So in bigger 100+ lists, also 100+ cells are created --> wasted at startup.

Ist there another possibility to get this information when the cell is set up like this? Is it really neccessary to built the switch case sturcture again in heightForRowAtIndexPath to avoid these calls and though get the right heights for each cell?

Would it be better to hold a "datasource-list" with the single information of each cell?

But how to handle the different cell styles, custom cells.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two possibilities:

1. How many cells you have? If you have a small number of cells (which seems to be the case here), you don't need cell reusing! In general, cell reusing is overused.
   Just create cells when you are creating your controller or when you have updated your data and put them into a `NSArray`.
    
   Then you can return them from `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` or measure their height.
2. Create a separate method that returns cell text/font and use it in both delegate methods instead of reading the information from the cell directly.

Comment: 1. I have very few cells. About 10 maybe. So you wouldn't use the reuse thing of UITableView and set up the cells in the viewDidLoad holding them in an extra array? But how would you now calculate the height of different styled cells?

2. That's like building the switch case again in an extra method, because the data is not holded in a list or sth. 

Is there maybe a beter way to present data than doing it with a tableview?

Comment: Your problem is that you are calling one delegate method from another delegate method. If you create the cells beforehand, you can use them in both your delegate methods and no new objects will be created.

Comment: "or measure their height" - to do that I would first have to force the cells to layout - at a point where they aren't even added to the tableview yet! How could I do that?

Comment: @de If you know what information should be displayed in the cell, just calculate the size needed to display that information. You don't need to rely on layout. That's why there are all the methods `sizeWithFont:` and similar.

Comment: @Sulthan I understand that – but then, what's the point in pre-creating the cells? I still have to calculate the height by hand, taking tableViewStyle, cell image view, cell accessory view, detail-label etc into account. I was hoping to get around this with your promising approach.

Comment: @de It enables you to put the functionality into the code for the cell to have everything in one place.

Comment: @Sulthan True – I'll try that for my new implementation. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

The method

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

is called for each cell before the method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

So in the first method, cells are not yet created, and you should not try to access them.

When you create a tableView, the data source is first asked for the number of row. Then for each row, the data source is asked for the height of the row, so that the tableView know the total height of it's content, and then finally, the data source is asked for the cell (actual view) to display.

In your case, i would built the switch case structure again. Concerning the "datasource-list", I have never done it before, so maybe it's a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an array of strings in objects and are using the standard table cell then try this iOS 7 compatible magic:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSString* text = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSAttributedString * attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text attributes:
                                             @{ NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18]}];

    //its not possible to get the cell label width since this method is called before cellForRow so best we can do
    //is get the table width and subtract the default extra space on either side of the label.
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(tableView.frame.size.width - 30, MAXFLOAT);

    CGRect rect = [attributedString boundingRectWithSize:constraintSize options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading) context:nil];

    //Add back in the extra padding above and below label on table cell.
    rect.size.height = rect.size.height + 23;

    //if height is smaller than a normal row set it to the normal cell height, otherwise return the bigger dynamic height.
    return (rect.size.height < 44 ? 44 : rect.size.height);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see – you have only two cell types.
So you might have a `@property` for each type of cell (please take a look to an example below):

```
static NSString * const kCellIdentifier = @"kCellIdentifier";

@interface ...
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITableViewCell *cell;
@end

@implementation
@synthesize cell = cell_;

...

- (UITableViewCell *)cell {
    if (!cell_) {
        cell_ = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:kCellIdentifier];
    }
    return cell_;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)cellForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        //put it to autorelease pool to avoid EXC_BAD_ACCESS
        cell = [[self.cell retain] autorelease];
        self.cell = nil;
    }
    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = self.cell;
    CGFloat height = 24 + [@"text" sizeWithFont:cell.detailTextLabel.font constrainedToSize: (CGSize){cell.detailTextLabel.frame.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX} lineBreakMode:cell.detailTextLabel.lineBreakMode].height;
    return MAX(height, 44.0f);
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self cellForTableView:tableView];
    cell.detailTextLabel = @"text";
    return cell;
}
```

So the cell would be initialized only once in the beginning.