# Definitive tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: solution

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

Ok, This is an old issue almost every iOS developer has struggled with. Many answers on the subject are a available.

However I still haven't found a really **practical, generic solution** for calculating a `UITableViewCell`'s height in `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`.

I understand how the layout mechanism of `UITableView` works (it calculates the height of the whole table before actually laying out any cells).
I also understand that one basically has to anticipate everything that will happen in `UITableViewCell`s layout method using for example `sizeWithFont:...` methods on `NSString`.

I assume that the style of the cell is `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle` to begin with (we can get more generic later!).

These would be my requirements:

- the cell might be in a grouped or plain tableView
- the system version might be iOS 6 or iOS 7+
- an image might or might not be set in `cell.imageView`
- an accessory view might or might not be set
- `cell.textLabel` might or might not contain text.
- `cell.detailTextLabel` might or might not contain text.
- fonts might be customized
- the labels might be multi-line
- the table width is arbitrary (portrait, landscape, iPad...)
- the number of cells is limited (probably some dozen)

In most cases this kind of dynamic cell would be used in short lists (maybe some kind of detail view) so I think it would be viable to pre-calculate the cells like described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8832778/921573

I am looking for an implementation for calculating the cell height that satisfies the given requirements.
I'd be very happy if anyone could share some insights & experience - thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could keep a single dummy cell in your table view's delegate and let it calculate its own required size.

Answer (score -1):

The best way to make custom cells with different heights is:

make a `NSMutableArray` for cells:

```
@property (nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray* cellsArray;
```

then in m.:

the first method which call is

```
-(float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
```

make your cell here:

```
    -(float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        if (!self.cellsArray) {

            self.cellsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        }

        ListCell* cell = [[ListCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];


       // IMPLEMENT your custom cell here, with custom data, with custom,different height:

       // after add this cell to your array:
        [self.cellsArray addObject:cell];

       // IMPORTANT STEP:  set your cell height for the new height:

        cell.frame = CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x, cell.frame.origin.y, 303, yourLastItemInCell.frame.origin.y + yourLastItemInCell.frame.size.height);


        return cell.frame.size.height;
    }
```

after you got the custom cells with different heights :

```
#pragma mark - conform to delegates

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return 10;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    return self.cellsArray[indexPath.row];

}
```

I hope it helps !

EDIT:

```
tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:frame style: UITableViewStylePlain];
tableView.delegate = self;
tableView.dataSource = self;
tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

Comment: I think this wouldn't handle the requirement 'the cell might be in a grouped or plain tableView', would it?

Comment: is the missing element intended: 'CGRectMake(0, 0,, 50)'?

Comment: Ah ok – so u are suggesting to implement my own grouped style drawing & layout for the grouped style case?

Comment: If you implement your own tableview and cells like this, you could make a cell as custom as you want. The height won't be a problem !